# How to handle master detail update and delete request in JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

We have the JSON Data coming in this format,

```
$invoice_data = {
    "CONTACT_ID": "1",
    "INV_SERIAL_NO": "100",
    "NAME": "baby",
    "INV_DATE": "2018-06-27",
    "DUE_DATE": "2018-06-27",
    "CURRENCY": "KD",
    "SUBTOTAL": "143",
    "TAX_TOTAL": "13",
     "shipment_data": [
         {
            "SHIP_SERIAL_NO": "44",
            "MASTER_NO": "55",
            "HOUSE_NO": "88",
            "cost_revenue_items": [
                {
                    "CHARGE_REF": "tt",
                    "CURRENCY": "INR",
                    "QUANTITY": "2",
                    "SELLING_RATE": "45",
                    "EXCHANGE_RATE": "987"                                       
                },{
                    "CHARGE_REF": "ii",
                    "CURRENCY": "INR",
                    "QUANTITY": "2",
                    "SELLING_RATE": "45",
                    "EXCHANGE_RATE": "456"
                },{
                    "CHARGE_REF": "op",
                    "CURRENCY": "INR",
                    "QUANTITY": "2",
                    "SELLING_RATE": "45",
                    "EXCHANGE_RATE": "456"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How to write DELETE End-point for child data-set “cost_revenue_items”. What I mean to say is how to handle the request to delete one of item from “cost_revenue_items”.

When “cost_revenue_items” will be deleted ,master “invoice_data” will be updated. This update , we can handle by PUT, but how do we know under that PUT, we have to
DELETE one of “cost_revenue_items”. Like how the JSON request to only delete one of “cost_revenue_items” will look like.

Will JSON request to delete “cost_revenue_items” looks like this ,if it want to delete last record :

```
$invoice_data = {
    "CONTACT_ID": "1",
    "INV_SERIAL_NO": "100",
    "NAME": "baby",
    "INV_DATE": "2018-06-27",
    "DUE_DATE": "2018-06-27",
    "CURRENCY": "KD",
    "SUBTOTAL": "143",
    "TAX_TOTAL": "13",
     "shipment_data": [
         {
            "SHIP_SERIAL_NO": "44",
            "MASTER_NO": "55",
            "HOUSE_NO": "88",
            "cost_revenue_items": [
                {
                    "CHARGE_REF": "tt",
                    "CURRENCY": "INR",
                    "QUANTITY": "2",
                    "SELLING_RATE": "45",
                    "EXCHANGE_RATE": "987"
                },{
                    "CHARGE_REF": "ii",
                    "CURRENCY": "INR",
                    "QUANTITY": "2",
                    "SELLING_RATE": "45",
                    "EXCHANGE_RATE": "456"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Kindly help me to know , how JSON request will look like ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just send the `CHARGE_REF`and the `INV_SERIAL_NO` if the charge ref is not unique

Comment: Thanks for the reply..                                                                                                                            I am already comparing CHARGE_REF and the INV_SERIAL_NO and inserting record, but what if a record is already existing in our database and the JSON request comes without that record. My question is how should we delete that in our database in the same put request or they will send a separate delete request for that?